# Making an object detect that raycast not hitting it anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I use SendMessage to inform the Object that is was hit by a Raycast:

```
     using UnityEngine;

 public class Raycaster : MonoBehaviour {
     void Update() {
         RaycastHit hit;
         if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
          if(hit.transform.tag == "MyGameObject"){
            hit.transform.SendMessage ("HitByRay");
            }  
     }
 }
```

And object have a script like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

 public class ObjectHit : MonoBehaviour {
     void HitByRay () {
         Debug.Log ("I was hit by a Ray");
     }
 }
```

And that print message "I was hit by Ray" in every frame.
Now i need to inform that Game Object that raycast not hitting it anymore.

Comment: store a reference to the object hit last time, if the new object != the last object, or the raycast doesnt hit anything this time, tell the object its not getting hit anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eddge is right, storing a reference to the hit gameobject is the way to go. Check the following code :

```
public class Raycaster : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private bool hitting = false;
     private GameObject hitObject;

     void Update()
     {
         RaycastHit hit;
         if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
         {
            if(hit.transform.tag == "MyGameObject")
            {
                GameObject go = hit.transform.gameobject ;

                // If no registred hitobject => Entering
                if( hitObject == null )
                {
                    go.SendMessage ("OnHitEnter"); 
                }
                // If hit object is the same as the registered one => Stay
                else if( hitObject.GetInstanceID() == go.GetInstanceID() )
                {
                    hitObject.SendMessage( "OnHitStay" );
                }
                // If new object hit => Exit last + Enter new
                else
                {
                    hitObject.SendMessage( "OnHitExit" );
                    go.SendMessage ("OnHitEnter");
                }

                hitting = true ;
                hitObject = go ;
            } 
         }
         // No object hit => Exit last one
         else if( hitting )
         {
            hitObject.SendMessage( "OnHitExit" );
            hitting = false ;
            hitObject = null ;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was hepful. But can i do that somehow with WHILE loop, i think  it requires much less code? For example sending message to object "Hit" and put script on that object like, while(i receive message "Hit"){ do something }

Comment: I don't think it will require less code. I suggested to use the 3 functions `OnHitEnter`, `OnHitStay` and `OnHitExit` so as to be flexible. You just have to implement the given functions in a script you attach to the possible targets of your raycasts. If you want, you could have on the target object a variable `hit` you set to `true` in `OnHitEnter` and to `false` in `OnHitExit`, and then, in the `Update` function the following condition `if( hit ) { doSomething() ; }`

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you helped me with a problem I have spent nearly three days trying to work out (I am new to C programming). Thank you so much :D