# Change SKSpriteNode.isHidden to false when hit by raycast, otherwise set it to true

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to create a line of sight/field of view on a 2d game and am having some issues. I currently am trying a raycast as a solution. The idea is that by default all my enemy nodes have `isHidden = true`. When the raycast hits them it should change that value to be `false` and when the raycast is no longer hitting them it should change it back to `true`.

I've messed around with a lot of different options here. I have tried keeping track of the raycast hit variable like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983775/making-an-object-detect-that-raycast-not-hitting-it-anymore).

I currently have it set up in an if-else statement to handle it, but this ends up having the sprites flash in and out if the raycast is hitting and then will leave `isHidden = false` if it was true originally.

```
 scene?.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(alongRayStart: rayStart, end: rayEnd) { (body, point, normal, stop) in
    let sprite = body.node as? SKSpriteNode
    if body.categoryBitMask == 2 {
        sprite?.isHidden = true
    }else if body.categoryBitMask == 1 {

    } else { sprite?.isHidden = true }
}
```

I have the above code as part of a function that I am then calling in the update() function.

I expect the sprite to have the value of `isHidden = false` only when currently being hit by the raycast. Unfortunately it isn't working that way.

Comment: Use `SKNode`'s `userData` property.

Comment: @ElTomato something like `enemy.userData.setValue(raycastHit: false)` and then set that to true when being hit?

Comment: Close...  enemy.userData = ["raycastHit": false]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first have all my enemies in a special node container in the scene,  then before casting a ray, reset the enemies `isHidden` property by using a forloop.

```
enemyContainer.children.forEach{$0.isHidden = false}
scene?.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(alongRayStart: rayStart, end: rayEnd) { (body, point, normal, stop) in
    if let sprite = body.node as? SKSpriteNode,sprite.categoryBitMask & ~0b1 \\Replace 0b1 with your category bit mask constant if you created one
        sprite.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

This will allow you to immediately figure out if a light is touching an enemy, as opposed to E.Coms answer, which will only tell you when an enemy is hit during the physics update phase

if you do not want your enemies in a special container, then you can create an array and store only the ones that were touched the last time the ray was cast

```
//Global to class
var nodesInLight = [SKNode]()
```

.......

```
//in func

nodesInLight.forEach{$0.isHidden = false}
nodesInLight = [SKNode]() //Allow ARC to remove the previous container, instead of calling clear on it
scene?.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(alongRayStart: rayStart, end: rayEnd) { (body, point, normal, stop) in
    if let sprite = body.node as? SKSpriteNode,sprite.categoryBitMask & ~0b1 \\Replace 0b1 with your category bit mask constant if you created one
        sprite.isHidden = true
        nodesInLight.append(sprite)
    }
}
```

An advance technique I would do is create an array of weak references, this way you do not accidentally create a retain cycle

Comment: Ah this is genius. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey man, you've been super helpful for me on a couple posts and I have run into another issue. SO won't let me post unfortunately. Is there a way I can get your assistance?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may give the ray a real physicsbody, and implement the contact delegate. In the DidBegin func, to turn the enemy on. and DidEnd func, turn the enemy off.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("begin")

}

func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
     print("end")
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    view.showsPhysics = true

    let ray = SKShapeNode()

    ray.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 20)).cgPath
    ray.fillColor = UIColor.red
    addChild(ray)
    ray.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:(ray.path?.boundingBoxOfPath)!.size)
    ray.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ray.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(Float.pi * 2), duration: 3)))
    ray.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
      ray.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize.init(width: 100, height: 100))
     enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: enemy.frame.size)
     enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
     enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
     enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
     enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
     addChild(enemy)
     enemy.isHidden = true
     physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Comment: You do not need to call `.init()` that should only be used in constructors.

Comment: I don't want. But if I input .init(), Xcode would give me a lot of suggestion . Those are what I want.

Comment: if you just do `SKShapeNode(`, XCode will also tell you all of the suggestions that you are suppose to use with that class